# Practising python list and if

Tags: python

When i was practising list&if in python i got stuck with a problem

```
friends=["a","b","c"]
print("eklemek mi cikarmak mi istiyosunuz  ?")
ans=(input())
if ans == 'add':
  add=input("adding who  ?")
  friends.append(add)
if ans=='remove':
  remove = input("removing who ?")
  friends.remove(remove)
print(remove)
```

the code is above works fine but when  i want to improve it with already existing friends and not having that friend i got stuck and having this error =  if add in list:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable same goes to not having that friend to remove

```
friends=["a","b","c"]
print("add or remove ?  ?")
ans=(input())
if ans == 'add':
  add=input("adding who ? ?")
  if add in friends:
    print("you already added this person")
  else :
    friends.append(add)
if ans=='remove':
   remove = input("removing who ?")
   friends.remove(remove)
print(friends)
```

Comment: `if add in list` ??? `list`??? list is a inbuilt type

Comment: ` if add in list:` here is your error you are trying to check in keyword it should be `if add in friends`

Comment: oh i didnt realized but the same thing doesnt work for removing if ans=='remove':
   remove = input("removing who ?")
if remove not in friends:
 print("there is no one named that ")
 friends.remove(remove)
print(friends) but having this error name'remove' can be undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
friends=["a","b","c"]
print("add or remove ?  ?")
ans=(input())
if ans == 'add':
  add=input("adding who ? ?")
  if add in list:
    print("you already added this person")
  else :
    friends.append(add)
if ans=='remove':
   remove = input("removing who ?")
   if remove in friends: 
       friends.remove(remove)
   else:
        print('remove doesnot exist in list')
print(friends)
```

Comment: yes i realised i typed list instead of friends but when i try the same thing with in remove function  not in friends having this error name 'remove' can be undefined

Comment: thank you for that but im trying to code if there is no one named remove input in friends list print("no one named exists in your friends")

Comment: friends=["a","b","c"]
print("add or remove ?  ?")
ans=(input())
if ans == 'add':
  add=input("adding who ? ?")
  if add in friends:
    print("you already added this person")
  else :
    friends.append(add)
if ans=='remove':
 remove = input("removing who ?")
 if remove not in friends:
  print("there is no one named that ")
 else :
  friends.remove(remove)
print(friends)

thank you , i did this and it works

Answer (score 0):

okay i solved it i dont know whether its perfect but it works

```
friends=["a","b","c"]
print("add or remove ?  ?")
ans=(input())

    if ans == 'add':
      add=input("adding who ? ?")
      if add in friends:
        print("you already added this person")
      else :
        friends.append(add)
    if ans=='remove':
     remove = input("removing who ?")
     if remove not in friends:
      print("there is no one named that ")
     else :
      friends.remove(remove)
    print(friends)
```